# Получение коллекции из Firestore

Tags: java, android-studio

В Cloud Firestore у меня создана: коллекция -> документ -> поле в Map

```
collection -> document -> values
valuesl:
key1:a
key2:b
key3:C
```

Как мне получить этот Map в коде? В самой программе мне нужно получить данные из БД. Отдельно записать ключи и отдельно значения. Ума не приложу как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Что ж, можно реализовать это и через мапу, но по факту вы все равно получите ответ в виде:

```
{key1=a, key2=b, key3=c};
```

Я с подобной ситуацией сталкивался. Для себя я нашел такое решение: с учетом того, что в моей базе работали разные люди и ключи могли быть абсолютно разные и в любой момент изменяемые:
Создавал обычные переменные String, в поля в БД добавлял ему приставку, пр-р: `base://`, а к значению в конец ставил любой уникальный символ, вроде `!!!`

В коде получал одной строкой весь этот хлам:

```
{base://key1=a!!!, base://key2=b!!!, base://key3=c!!!}
```

А дальше паттернами гнал в массивы:
Ответ с БД сохраняете в переменную

```
String start = "{base://key1=a!!!, base://key2=b!!!, base://key3=c!!!}";

ArrayList<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();

Matcher matcher_key = Pattern.compile("base://" + "(.*?)=").matcher(start);
        while (matcher_key.find()) {
            key.add(matcher_key.group(1));
        }

ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

Matcher matcher_value = Pattern.compile("=" + "(.*?)!!!").matcher(start);
        while (matcher_value.find()) {
            val.add(matcher_value.group(1));
        }
```

Ну и лепим в мапу:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < key.size();i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                map.put(key.get(i), val.get(j));
            }
```

Я надеюсь, что это вам поможет. Я только учусь и, возможно, можно было бы грамотнее написать этот кусок кода.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то как раз подходит для моих целей!